# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I keep getting this SyntaxError when reading json parameters from a rest api in javascript.

Any clue what it might be?

I appreciate any help

code:

```
     parseJSONResponse : function(inResult) {
     var jsonDoc = JSON.parse(inResult);

    this.fmeForm =  document.forms['fmeForm'];

    ar parameters = jsonDoc.serviceResponse.parameters.parameter;
    for( i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {

        if(parameters[i].type === "LOOKUP_CHOICE") {
            this.createComboBox(parameters);
        }
        if(parameters[i].type === "LISTBOX_ENCODED") {
            this.createCheckboxGroup(parameters);
        }
    }
},
```

And the json from a rest look like this:

```
      "serviceResponse": {
      "parameters": {"parameter": [
  {
     "optionsType": "MULTICHOICE_CONFIG",
     "type": "LISTBOX_ENCODED",
     "options": {"option": [
        {"value": "NOR"},
        {"value": "NOR_roads"}
     ]}
  },
  {
     "optionsType": "SINGLECHOICE_CONFIG",
     "type": "LOOKUP_CHOICE",
     "options": {"option": [
        {
           "displayAlias": "WGS84, Lat-Long; Degrees [LL84]",
           "value": "EPSG:4326"
        }
     ]}
  },
  {
     "name": "GEOM",
     "description": "",
     "defaultValue": "<lt>?xml<space>version=<quote>1.0<quote><space>encoding=     <quote>US_ASCII<quote><space>standalone=<quote>no<quote><space>?<gt><lt>geometry<gt>  <lt>polygon<gt><lt>line<gt><lt>coord<space>x=<quote>-124<quote><space>y=<quote>48<quote><solidus><gt><lt>coord<space>x=<quote>-124<quote><space>y=<quote>49.399999999999999<quote><solidus><gt><lt><solidus>line<gt><lt><solidus>polygon<gt><lt><solidus>geometry<gt>",
     "optionsType": "SINGLECHOICE_CONFIG",
     "type": "GEOMETRY",
     "options": {"option": {"value": "GEOM"}}
  },
```

Thanx!

Comment: That's not a complete JSON literal.  What is the exact value of `inResult`, and what does it come from?

Comment: @SLaks: What's a "JSON literal"?  It's either a "JSON string" or an "object literal".

Comment: Most likely there's an unclosed parentheses or quote mark in the JSON -- looks like you haven't posted the full JSON here.  One thing I like to try is to paste my JSON into http://jsoneditoronline.org/, which will format it nicely (if it's valid) and give an error message if not.

Comment: It's also possible that parseJSONResponse is not called correctly.

Answer (score 5):

as everyone is stating, this is absolutely not a valid JSON, whatever the case, try validating your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/, this will show you exactly where your problem might be

Answer (score 0):

That is either a excerpt from the JSON response or a very broken result. One problem is that the comma at the end makes it invalid JSON...